# Why are failed credit card contributions appearing as default payment method?

Tags: civicontribute, payment, payment-method

I know this could likely be related to [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33759/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-pending-pay-later-payment-method), [this one](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27782/pay-later-payment-method-does-not-get-overwritten-when-payment-is-made) and [this other](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26314/whats-the-logic-behind-contributions-payment-method-for-offline-contributions) stack - but bringing it up as its a bit different.

When a credit card transaction fails - it is correctly marked as failed in the system - but the Payment Method listed is actually the default payment method and not Credit Card. Is this all the same issue?

Comment: This seems different @themak; I've seen that other bug, but not this one.  What payment processor are you using?

Comment: Cybersource - Omnipay
I do have some failed transactions from last year that correctly identify Credit Card - but at somepoint that changed. (I also don't recall ever manually changing those to Credit Card - so I am pretty sure the system did it automatically.)